# Problem with "element not reachable by keyboard" in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having a problem in Selenium Webdriver.

I need to upload a file for a site. Here is what I tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".icon-upload-cloud"))
      .sendKeys(
          "C:"                    + File.separator +
          "Users"                 + File.separator +
          "Vinicius"              + File.separator +
          "OneDrive"              + File.separator +
          "Arquivos para códigos" + File.separator +
          "Logo empresa.png"
      );
```

The problem is the button to upload is returning the error: `"element is not reachable by keyboard"`.

I can solve the problem with this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    .until(
        ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
            By.cssSelector(".icon-upload-cloud")
        )
    )
    .click();
```

But then I don't know how to upload a file because Windows opens a file selection dialog box, and I can't use `sendKeys()`.

Comment: I think you should edit html instead of uploading with upload button.

Answer (score 0):

“element not reachable by keyboard”

Means exactly the same thing you cannot interact with that element using keyboard

I think you are interacting with a button element instead of 'input' element

### if you want to upload using send_keys, you should be sending to element with input tag whos display property is not none, and is not disabled

Answer (score 0):

I did like this:

```
WebElement fileupload = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".icon-upload-cloud"));
    fileupload.click();    
    StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("C:\\Users\\Vinicius\\OneDrive\\Arquivos para códigos\\Arquivo de áudio.mp3"); 
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);                                     
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Thanks for the help :)